# How can I get many inputs from the user as list in python

Tags: python-3.x, input, split

I'd like to do an script that can get many inputs in a row as the user want and then create some list of that.

My first idea was create an unique input list and then split the sublist in the total of lists. Or there is a shorted way to do?

I've tried with this but I can't split the inputs in lists

`keys = list()
while True:
    line = input('Enter words: ').rstrip().lower()
    if line == 'done' or line == 'Done':
        break
    keys.append(line)
input_list = keys.split(',')`

The result is a lists in a list
`keys = ['a,b,c,d', 'z,x,w', 'value_n, value_n+1, value_n+n']`

But the output have to be:
`list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_2 = ['z', 'x', 'w']
list_n = ['value_n', 'value_n+1', 'value_n+n']`

Answer (score 0):

You could do `input('Enter words: ').rstrip().lower().split(',')` and have the user separate the values with just a comma, or `input('Enter words: ').rstrip().lower().split(', ')` and have the user separate the values with a comma and a space.

`[w.lstrip() for w in input('Enter words: ').rstrip().lower().split(',')]` accepts both types of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your code is fine. Just change the last line and you'll get list of list.

```py
input_list = [i.split(',') for i in keys]

# output:
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['z', 'x', 'w'], ['value_n', ' value_n+1', ' value_n+n']]
```

If this is not what you want, please comment below. You can access each element from a list by indexing. Check this quick example.

```py
>>> input_list  # you already have the values inside this variable
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['z', 'x', 'w'], ['value_n', ' value_n+1', ' value_n+n']]
>>>
>>> input_list[0]  # access the first element
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
>>> input_list[1]  # access the second element
['z', 'x', 'w']
>>>
>>> input_list[2]  # access the third element
['value_n', ' value_n+1', ' value_n+n']
```

Comment: How can I extract the information in each list to work with it?

Comment: Hello @ChachoFuva, I just update my answer. Please check it. Your `list_1` is similar to `input_list[0]`. Please check it and let me know if you stuck any point.

Comment: I'd like to do a loop to apply a 'function' to each list in 'input_list'.